# In Xcode, how do you re-add the Mac app's product back to the Project navigator?

Tags: xcode, macos

I accidentally removed from my Xcode Project Navigator the reference to the product of my Mac app target. Is there a way to re-add it to the Project navigator?

(I tried dragging in the actual built app, but that's a reference to that build's specific folder, which isn't the same thing.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Follow these steps to find the `Products` directory:**

1. Create a new Finder window, via Cmd+N
2. Select the Go menu and hold down the option key
3. You should see `Library`
4. Select `Library` and navigate to the directory below

Try adding this folder to your project navigator:

> /Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[APPLICATION_NAME]-[RANDOMLY-GENERATED_SUFFIX]/Build/Products

- Ensure `Copy items if needed` is not checked
- Ensure `Create groups` is selected
- Ensure a target is selected

I hope that helps!